# Google Analytics Regex: Filter Landingpages with only one directoy

Tags: regex, google-analytics

Basically I want to filter for pages in this format:

```
/page
```

but I don't want pages like this:

```
/dir/page/page

dir/page
```

Is there any way to accomplish this using the regex filter in Google Analytics?

I tried the following:

`/*/` but its not working at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (to match pages like **/home**):

```
^\/[0-9A-Za-z]+$
```

If you need to add other characters you can add it in the brackets (i.e. - and . to match pages like **/home**, **/store.html** or **/page-path**):

```
^\/[0-9A-Za-z\-\.]+$
```